# Use apt-get in chroot directory

Tags: apt, chroot

I am currently in need of using `apt-get` on a chroot directory.
The setup is the following.

I have a chroot setup with schroot.
This chroot environment needs to be stripped down as much as possible.
Therefore I am planning to remove apt-get and commin from the chroot environment.

I know that Gentoo has the possibility to use portage on a different root directory.
Is this possible to set a different root directory for apt.get to install software into my chroot directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `apt-get -o RootDir=your_dir install some-package` might be what your looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [debootstrap chroot.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot)

1. Install packages on the host computer.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install debootstrap
   sudo apt-get install schroot
   ```
2. Create a configuration file for schroot.
3. Run debootstrap.
4. Check the chroot.
5. Now you can use whatever you want, including installation using

   `apt-get`

The detailed instructions and more information can be found in the above link

Another useful link can be found [here](http://www.binarytides.com/setup-chroot-ubuntu-debootstrap/).

---

A simpler instructions:

Create a chroot environment into which you will install your packages:

```
debootstrap precise fakeInstallation
```

Replace "precise" with your Ubuntu version name, and "fakeInstallation" with directory you want to chroot.

Now you have created a fake installation in the `fakeInstallation` directory

```
chroot fakeInstallation
```

Now you can use apt-get install within the fakeInstallation directory

Comment: I dont want to use apt-get within the chroot environtment, but instead from my own and use the "global" apt-get to install stuff into the chroot without having apt-get installed inside the chroot

Comment: @raddirad Any chance you found out how to do this? I want to do something similar.