# Using apt-get install in chroot

Tags: 14.04, apt, server, chroot

I used `debootstrap` to create a `chroot` environment:

```
sudo debootstrap trusty trusty/
sudo chroot trusty
```

I'm using chroot. but command `apt-get` doesn't work:

```
I have no name!@user:/# apt-get install python
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

How can i use `apt-get` in `chroot`. Or, how can i install an specific application (for instance python), for chroot, so chroot can use it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use apt-get in chroot directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633645/use-apt-get-in-chroot-directory)

Comment: Is your `PATH` correct? What happens if you try `/usr/bin/apt-get`?

Comment: It didn't have `/trusty/bin/apt-get`. Tho i tried to copy it from the root:`cp -r /usr/bin/apt-get /trusty/bin/`. But the package needed another packages, so it would give another error that the package is not complete.