# Where can I find the System OOM deamon I keep getting errors due to no space on device

Tags: apt, snap, storage, gvfs, data-corruption

Below are a couple of things I'm getting back in terminal.  BTW I'm running "Try Ubuntu" from live USB in attempt to repair what is probably a corrupted beyond measure installation. It is good practice and learning opportunity for me, a novice at best.

1)
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to fill /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i with padding: No space left on device

2)
/$ sudo apt search "oomd"
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: how large is your live USB? how is it partitioned (ie is the partition where the OS is located only large enough to hold the OS and nothing else)?

Comment: When running on the stick, you are not in the environment of your installed image. Check out how to [chroot](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system) or [in this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633645/use-apt-get-in-chroot-directory)

Comment: THANK YOU! I'M SURE I SEEM TOTALLY DIM TO MANY PEOPLE ON HERE BC I'M SUCH A NOVICE!  BUT ANYTHING AT ALL YOU GUYS CAN OFFER IS DEEPLY APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: @ESTHER--16 GB — 12 GB free (24.7% full)

Comment: There is some weird way everything is configured as far as the file system indexing and swapping that I can't figure out.  I literally only put the .iso from the website to do the installation on that USB, however it is listed as "cdrom:" and buried in the regular files of the actual installed OS on a 1 TB HDD and then there is a loop device with "squash FS" that boots and runs no matter what that I can't gain ownership of or any permissions.  ???  Is this at all nornmal??

Comment: AskUbuntu is poorly suited to discussions or followup questions. Please edit your original question to ensure that you are asking the question that you want answered. You might need to ask multiple questions.

Comment: Please include all additional information in your question. Thanks.

Comment: It’s been a while but I need to add some information about what’s happening here: my apologies for being “meta” — I get it that y’all want specific questions targeted for getting a clear answer. However I have a weird situation where my installation is more facsimile than genuine and this is important for security reasons. I have come to find that despite choosing a basic ext4 installation from the live usb, my machine is running as an entirely virtual system. I had weird things coming from snapd and bc the install was not great anyway I decided to do an apt purge of anything “snap” (cont’d):

Comment: I just wanted to see what the system would be like without this (BIG) part of the OS there. I thought I’d probably have crashed my whole system. When all config files started deleting one by one, suddenly devices started appearing in my dock, each one a different memory sector and each a variation of an Ubuntu installation: bare, minimal, core18, core20, so on and so on. So snap was still there but in containers that had been installed without my knowledge or permission and that were “hidden” in plain sight as dev/loop0, loop1, loop2,…etc. (cont’d)

Comment: And of course this was locked in place via scripts run during boot sequence to prevent me from reverting my OWN system!  Then I discovered that all of my activities in terminal are being logged in detail esp. sudo commands. And that my terminal is setup as a slave “pts”, which is watched by god knows who, where, or why. I’m new to all of this but NOTHING about this feels right or normal. Do ANY of you know what this is all about??  Where it came from etc.??  I’m doing my own cancer surgery here but with a Swiss-army knife and raw uranium for the chemo—to analogize. Lol

Comment: @JTRichter'commander-prompt' A pseudo-terminal slave is perfectly normal in a GUI setup where I assume you are using a graphical terminal emulator and not a tty. This does not mean that someone is "watching" you. "Then I discovered that all of my activities in terminal are being logged in detail esp. sudo commands." Are you talking about your shell's history buffer? Also, snapd is an important part of modern verisons of Ubuntu and is the way many packages are installed by default. The devices on /dev/loop0..10 represent squashfs images that snapd loads the software from.

Comment: That’s the kind of thing that makes sense after you feel super embarrassed about your ignorance!  Lol. I do understand the importance of snap, but I also have had problems resulting from malware disguised as system admin configs etc on every OS I have tried over the last 9 months. This is a home PC not a workstation, so I don’t get why there are so many restrictions placed on me and the constant “governance“ for lack of a better word imposed on my system. I thought open-source would be “anti” towards all of that and back doors etc